# access Class in parent directory

Tags: python-3.10

While I can access and execute functions of a class, which reside in the same directory, I'm unable to invoke it from a subdirectory.

```
    from ..proxy import Proxy
    ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

I've roamed the documentation for the [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html), but could not make anything work.

This is my directory structure:

```
- root
  - code
    main.py
    proxy.py
    - tests
      mytest.py
```

The mytest.py should import the proxy.py.

```
from ..proxy import Proxy
```

Interestingly enough Visual Studio Code thinks the import statement is legit. Any clue anyone?

Btw, if I move the mytest.py one level up (same as the proxy.py) and adapt the import statement, it works smoothly.

(OS: Win11)

Answer (score 0):

To use relative imports, you must be inside a package.

In python, a package is any folder that includes an `__init__.py` file. It can be empty, but it has to exist.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Comment: The file must be called `__init__.py`, verbatim